# How do I make a lookup table constraint that if an entry 'Other' exists or is inserted, its PK Id must be -1?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints

I would like to ensure that on all lookup tables that contain an 'Other' entry, that the PK (Id) is -1. I have many business rules that are only activated when 'Other' is selected, so it kind of makes sense, for a first iteration at least, that all 'Other' entries have an identical Id I can use in the rules without having to always look up the Id of 'Other' when executing a rule.

Comment: Perhaps an `instead of insert` trigger that examines what new rows are to be inserted, and changes the ID to -1 if it is 'other'. If an ID does not already exist with value -1 that is :-)

Comment: It's just personal, but I am no at all very partial to triggers.

Comment: Doesn't bother me, Damien's solution works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check constraint, but of course, you have to remember to add it for each table

```
CREATE TABLE Lookup (
    LookupID int not null primary key,
    Name varchar(20) not null unique,
    constraint CK_Lookup_Other CHECK (
      (Name='Other' and LookupID=-1) or
      (Name!='Other' and LookupID!=-1)
    )
)
```